# Reading <img> style to Canvas (html5,js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have a canvas where the user make interactions, then a `<img>` for the final "product". The `<img>` tag has the style properly filled with the data URI of the first canvas.

I now need to fetch this  "canvas" as a element then transform it into a canvas object. Example:

```
var canvas = parent.document.getElementById('canvas_holder');
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.strokeStyle = '#f00';
//etc...
```

*canvas_holder* is the `<img>` tag with style set to real canvas data URI. How would I go to make this thinking work? I can **not** change the structure of the `<img>`, unfortunately.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: I don't understand what's the question. Can you precise what operation is missing ?

Comment: I have a <img> tag, the style parameter is filled with data URI of a canvas object. 

I later need to get this <img> tag as a canvas, like the example provided above (where canvas_holder is the img tag)

Comment: Let me give it another go.

I got this:

`<img src="transparent.png" id="canvas_holder" background-image: url(data:image/png;base64, _datauri here_ ); />`


I now need to do something like this:

`<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas_holder');
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.strokeStyle = '#f00';
</script>`

This obviously don't work - so any idea how to make it work the way I'm aiming for?

Comment: Are you trying to turn the image back into a canvas?

Comment: I'm trying to make the object 'canvas' into a canvas object, having the data-uri in the canvas_holder (which is a <img>).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the OP wants to tell us that the image is a combination of a foreground image `transparent.png` and a background image which is represented by its base64 encoded version. The only way I see is to grab the background image from

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = $('#canvas_holder').css('background-image').match(/url\("?'?(.*)"?'?\)/)[1];
//  If you don't want to use jQuery, you could get the background-image as
// image.src = document.getElementById('canvas_holder').style.backgroundImage.match(/url\("?'?(.*)"?'?\)/)[1];
```

and paste it onto the canvas.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('yourcanvasid');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
```

and then get the foreground image and paste it onto the same canvas

```
var foreGround = document.getElementById('canvas_holder');
ctx.drawImage(foreGround, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to mess with the base64-encoded version of the image. Just use

```
var img = document.getElementById('myImage'); // your <img>   

var can = document.getElementById('myCanvas'); // your <canvas>
can.width = img.width;
can.height = img.height;
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');

ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height); // draw the image onto the canvas
```

This should draw the image onto the canvas.

Comment: That wouldn't help me at all, as the actual juice is in the style attribute of the <img> tag, and from what I can see your code doesn't obtain that.

Comment: But does the image actually display the data contained in the style attribute? If not, you might want to set the `src` attribute to the base64 string in order to display the data and then use above code...

Comment: It does display the data contained in the style attribute. My aim is to export a PDF - but I only found ways to export PDFs from Canvas - and my <img> isn't going through as parameter, obviously.

Maybe I'm doing it harder than it really is?

Comment: Yeah, probably :-) You can just use my code to create the canvas from the image. It takes the image data just as it is displayed to create the canvas.

Comment: Well, it doesn't really work. It doesn't obtain the style.

Is there any way to do it using my "thinking"?

Comment: You don't need the style attribute. It doesn't matter as long as your <img> displays the data you want to copy onto the canvas. See this for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/VYTLX/
The base64-string is the same as the image referenced. But it doesn't matter, because you don't need it. The style attribute is used for CSS, not for base64 representations of images.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm probably unclear. I have the <img> tag and I want to generate an image (jpg, png) or PDF from it. The image should be exactly like the <img>, with style aswell.